# How do I register a Tomcat 6 server on NetBeans 6.9.1?

Tags: windows-7, tomcat6, netbeans-6.9

I have just downloaded NetBeans 6.9.1 for JavaEE and installed it with Tomcat 6.  Everything went fine and I can run NetBeans, start and stop Tomcat from within the IDE and add and remove servers at will.

However when I try and create a Java EE Enterprise Application project my server list is empty.

The message I get at the bottom of the wizard for creating projects is "No servers are registered in the IDE.  To register a server, click the "Add..." button.

If I add a new server from there the drop down list remains empty, however if I then cancel from the wizard and look at the server list (Tools | Server) I wind up with a duplicate Tomcat server in the list, but still no way of selecting it from the setup dialog for the project.  This means I cannot create a project and am stalled.

I have Googled and got nothing and looked at the NetBeans docs and got nothing, so thought I would ask here.  Has anyone else has encountered this problem?  Am I missing the magic "make this server show up in the wizard" button?

I am running Netbeans 6.9.1, Java 1.6, Tomcat 6.0.26 and Windows 7.

Comment: This isnt a solution to the problem above, but is relevent to Netbeans 6.9.1 with Tomcat 7.0.6. I installed tomcat after netbeans and could not run or debug web applications. Opened the tomcat zip file and copied catalina.bat,setclasspath.bat,startup.bat,shutdown.bat into my Tomcat 7.0/bin directory
I can now debug applications but still have to deploy them manually by pointing Tomcats Manager App at the war file in my applications dist folder.